# Dereference structure array items in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, copy

I have a problem with dereferencing my array objects with the following code.
What I would like to do is to copy the array elements of *pstructDocuments into a global vector. I know global variables are not the best way, but for testing purposes I would like to fill the global vector with the structure elements.

```
struct DOCUMENTS{
    wchar_t* TYPE;
    wchar_t* PATH;
}

std::vector<DOCUMENTS> CdeskDocumentsVec

void initDocuments(DOCUMENTS *pstructDocuments, int size){

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
     DOCUMENTS test1 = {};
     test1.PATH = pstructDocuments[i].PATH;
     test1.TYPE = pstructDocuments[i].TYPE;
     CdeskDocumentsVec.push_back(test1);
  }
}
```

I have been tested some copy functions but they did not work as expected. So I hope that someone can help me to find the solution for creating a global copy with all array elements.....

This

```
DOCUMENTS test1 = {};
test1.PATH = L"PATH_TEXT";
test1.TYPE = L"TYPE_TEXT";
CdeskDocumentsVec.push_back(test1);
```

works with defined and given Strings.

This

```
CdeskDocumentsVec.push_back(pstructDocuments[i]);
```

does not work. I think this has to do with the pointers...

Not working means I am not able to iterate through the vector and get access to the strings that are stored in the DOCUMENT structure in the pstructDocuments array...

UPDATE:
When I copy the data

```
const size_t len = wcslen(pstructDocuments[i].PATH);
test1.PATH = new wchar_t[len + 1];
wcsncpy(test1.PATH, pstructDocuments[i].PATH, len + 1);
```

it seems to work....

Comment: You need to be more detailed than just "did not work as expected". What did you expect, and how did it differ?

Comment: I don't think you need `test1`, you can just do `.push_back(pStructDocuments[i])`.

Comment: I would also like to know why you're doing this. If it is what I think it is, have you considered the new initialization syntax with C++11 which allows you to initialize a vector much like an array? Perhaps there is no need for code to do this copy, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Not knowing what exactly is not working, could it be a problem that you only do a shallow copy of the array? If the strings in `pstructDocuments` get freed after `initDocuments` you have invalid pointers in `CdeskDocumentsVec`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the strings from the pstructDocuments[i] instead of assigning them.  When you assign them you are storing the pointer to the original strings rather than to copies.  If the original strings are destroyed you have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I assume that this is exactly the problem. The background is that I will call the initDocuments function from an external program, which provides the pointer of the first array and belonging elements/strings. I guess that the pointers are not available in the global scope... Therfore I will try to copy the wchar values. I already tried strcpy which did not work either. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: @Jochen `std::wstring` is the way to go. Change `TYPE` and `PATH` and the other code can stay the same.

Comment: I am not sure if changing from wchar_t to wstring is an option because I will use the structure "extern"...